# Stored procedure - Use array list in SQL query for insert in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If i have created/generated a list of elements during processing in stored procedure say rownum = [1,2,3,4].
Now i want to use this list in a sql statement to filter out rows say select * from mytable where rownum not in (1,2,3,4) in same stored procedure.
How can i achieve this ?
Please guide.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to this would be to use [binding variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html). However, set types are not supported as [bind variables in the Stored Procedure APIs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-stored-procedures-binding-variables) currently.

The JavaScript APIs do permit you to generate your SQL dynamically using [string and array transform functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), so the following approaches can be taken to work around the problem.

Inline the list of values into the query by forming a SQL syntax of a set of values:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE()
    RETURNS RETURNTYPE
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
      var lst = [2, 3, 4]
      var lstr = lst.join(',') // "2, 3, 4"
      var sql_command = `SELECT * FROM T WHERE C NOT IN (${lstr})` // (2, 3, 4)
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} )
      // Runs: SELECT * FROM T WHERE C NOT IN (2, 3, 4) [Literal query string]
      [...]
    $$;
```

Or if the list of values used could be unsafe, you can generate the query to carry just the right number of bind variables:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAMPLE()
    RETURNS RETURNTYPE
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
      var lst = [2, 3, 4]
      var lst_vars = Array(lst.length).fill("?").join(", ") // "?, ?, ?"
      var sql_command = `SELECT * FROM T WHERE C NOT IN (${lst_vars})` // (?, ?, ?)
      var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command, binds: lst} )
      // Runs: SELECT * FROM T WHERE C NOT IN (2, 3, 4) [After bind-substitution]
      [...]
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has the ARRAY_CONTAINS(  ,  ) function.

example:
Array_Contains( 5, array_construct( 1,2,3,4))